# wxPython - How to set an editor for a column of a grid

Tags: python, wxpython

The [docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.GridCellEditor.html#wx-grid-gridcelleditor) for `wx.grid.GridCellEditor` say

> Instances of `wx.grid.GridCellEditor` ... can be associated with the cell attributes for individual cells, rows, columns, or even for the entire grid.

Now, I know how to associate an editor with a cell:

```
self.mygrid.SetCellEditor(row, 1, wx.grid.GridCellEditorSubclass())
```

And I know how to associate an editor with an entire grid:

```
self.mygrid.SetDefaultEditor(wx.grid.GridCellEditorSubclass())
```

But I don't know how to set an editor for a single column. This obvious workaround is not a good solution:

```
for row in range(nrows):
    self.mygrid.SetCellEditor(row, 1, wx.grid.GridCellEditorSubclass())
```

because if I add rows to the grid (which is a common operation), the new rows don't have the editor until I specifically set it again.

The other obvious workaround is to associate a generic editor class with the entire grid and instantiate a column-specific editor at runtime based on the column number.

The documentation  clearly implies that I shouldn't have to resort to either workaround. But it also doesn't offer (at least anywhere I can find) another way to do it.

So, the question is, how do I set an editor for an entire grid column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach in the other two answers is to create a datatype, associate an editor with the datatype, and and then associate the datatype with a column. Decoupling the editor from the column number is a good idea if you have multiple columns with the same datatype, and so these solutions are probably the best generic approach.

But I wanted a simpler approach that associates an editor with a specific column because, in my application, every column is a different datatype. Sharing the datatype across columns makes no sense. So this answer is a closer fit to the original question.

It all revolves around the confusingly named class `wx.grid.GridCellAttr`. You could be forgiven for assuming that the name element `Attr` essentially means alignment and colour, because that is what it means in, for example, `wx.TextAttr`. And the most clearly documented constructor of this class is `GridCellAttr(colText, colBack, font, hAlign, vAlign)` which again suggests that `Attr` is about alignment and colour.

But the class `wx.grid.GridCellAttr` is actually a very generic cell properties descriptor class with over 30 methods for setting and getting alignment and colour, as expected, but also (among other things) size, read/write mode, renderer, and *editor*.

So the way to set an editor for the column of a grid is

```
my_col_property_settings = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
my_col_property_settings.SetEditor(MyColumnSpecificEditor())
my_col_property_settings.SetAlignment(hAlign=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, vAlign=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
# ... etc ...
self.mygrid.SetColAttr(1, my_col_property_settings)
```

But if you want to set the same editor for two columns, do not call `SetColAttr()` with the same instance of `GridCellAttr`, because you will get reference count errors at program shutdown if you do. Instead, do

```
self.mygrid.SetColAttr(1, my_col_property_settings.Clone())
self.mygrid.SetColAttr(2, my_col_property_settings.Clone())
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution for this, a method name something like "SetDefaultEditorForColumn", does not seem to exist.

But I think that the idea with Grid is to specify an editor for a data type rather than for a single column. This way you can have more than one column with the same data type in your grid and use the same editor.

That's where `Grid.RegisterDataType(self, typeName, renderer, editor)` makes its entry.

If you only want to modify only one of the two, renderer or editor, you may also want to call `Grid.GetDefaultRendererForType()` and `Grid.GetDefaultEditorForType()`.

Comment: Doesn't that just move the problem? I would have to register custom data types, because the columns contain strings drawn from different sets. And there is also no obvious way to set the data type of a column, only for cells. So, when I add a row, I would have to set the data type of each added cell, which is no less work than setting the editor directly.

Comment: Have a look at the grid method ˋSetColFormatCustomˋ, this may be what you‘re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that function performed by the following? :

- SetColFormatBool(col)
- SetColFormatFloat(col)
- SetColFormatNumber(col)
- SetColFormatCustom(col, typeName)

These functions set both the editor and renderer for the column in question.